# Can you turn a large airliner using only rudder input?

Tags: airliner, flight-controls, rudder

Is it possible to turn a large jet like the Boeing 747, Airbus A380 or other airliner using only the rudder, i.e. without using the ailerons on the wings?  Will it take longer to turn to a new heading? I find the tilting when ailerons (wing flaps) are involved is uncomfortable.

Comment: Duplicate of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29606/167) which is itself a duplicate of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/24101/167)

Comment: «I find the tilting when ailerons (wing flaps) are involved is uncomfortable.» Besides the fact that flaps and ailerons are very different things, where did you experience this? In a well-executed (aileron) turn you should hardly notice anything.

Answer (score 7):

Yes you can, and this is the backup mode for turning the A320 when the Fly By Wire has failed. It is not very comfortable though:

- Changing direction using only the rudder creates sideways acceleration, not good for passengers with drinks in front of them
- Since the rudder is located above the center of gravity, the aircraft leans the wrong way when rudder only is used, amplifying the sideways acceleration. A ship has the rudder below the center of buoyancy and leans into the turn when rudder is deflected.

Comment: Actually, I'm told by someone who should know that the difference between a **ship** and a **boat** is which way it heels over in a turn; a boat heels inward, a ship heels *outward*.  This is why submarines are always "boats" to sailors.